# Ionic 4 with Sqlite - Cannot read property 'then' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic-framework, electron

My database is not getting created. When I see my console, it shows the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>       at new HomePage (home.page.ts:31)

I have installed `npm install @ionic-native/sqlite@beta --save`

Below is my `home.page.ts` code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private sqlite: SQLite){
  this.sqlite.create({
    name: 'ionicdb.db',
    location: 'default'
  })
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS expense2(rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, date TEXT, type TEXT, description TEXT, amount INT)', [])
    .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
    .catch(e => console.log(e, 'err'));
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e)); 
}
}
```

I have done as per the documentation but dont know why this error is still there.

My project's `ionic info -v` for your reference:

```
ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.8.0 (C:\Users\jessica\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-rc.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.11.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.1.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.1.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.2.2

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : none
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (2 plugins total)

System:

 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.15.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.0.1
   OS                : Windows 8.1
```

Comment: Have you added SQLite plugin in your APP? refer this:https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/

Comment: I have mentioned that i have already installed it

Comment: I am talking about native SQLite plugin: ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage

Comment: I have added this, is it ok or i need to add some other? -  ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage

Comment: If you added these 2 then make sure you are calling it after platform.ready event and running the APP in emulator or physical device.

Comment: I do ionic serve, once it works with it, then i need to make exe of my project using electron

Comment: You need to build APK file using ionic cordova build android command. and intall it in Android emulator or device.

Comment: I am not doing this for android, i need to do for windows

Comment: have you reached a solution? Kindly do share

Comment: No solution, electron sqlite boilerplate from github is also giving errors when trying to install

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue. sqlite isn't available in browser naturally. So, if you just install the plugin, and do ionic serve, it's not going to work. Run these commands:

`ionic cordova platform add browser`

and then

`ionic cordova run browser`

I had to run the 2nd command twice. With the first command, it didn't build for me. After this, it worked.

Comment: this command give error like:  Using cordova-fetch for cordova-browser@^6.0.0
Platform browser already added.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
        
        cordova platform add browser exited with exit code 1.